# ffmpeg - Video Audio Capture with Compression

Tags: pi-3, ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg script that captures webcam video and microphone audio and then uses video compression before saving the audio/video mp4 file. The script works on my desktop but cause error on my Pi. ffmpeg does not crash but instead says two erros. 1) Queue input is backward in time. 2) Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 232, current: 218: changing to 232. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

ffmpeg command :

```
 ffmpeg -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 5000 -framerate 25 -video_size 
 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 5000 -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 
 -c:v libx264 -ac 1 -ar 44100 -c:a aac -y 
 ~/Desktop/ffmpegTesting/money.mp4
```

Is there a fix or does the Pi no have enough ram or something? My ram levels are jumping between 80-98 percent when I run this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash script was causing crashing becauses it was being fired through nodeJs spawn process. The process size was to big and caused crash. Fixed by configuring spawn process configurations.

Comment: And what exactly did you do?

Comment: Appended the following options to my spawn process child; detached:true and stdio:ignore

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.